# How to keep state immutable if state is of Set type? How to make copy of javascript Set type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, set

I start my `redux` reducer this way:

```
export default (state =  new Set( [5, 10, 15, 20], action)=>{
...
```

and right after this I shoud make a clone of the state:

if the state is an `Array`, I do

```
  let newState = [...state];
```

if the state is an `Object`, I do

```
   let newState = {...state};
```

The question is: what have I to do when the state is of `Set` type? Is here simple way to make `Set` clone?

Comment: Is there a reason why you use Set? Complex objects don't play well with Redux. It's beneficial to keep the state serializable.

Comment: First, is seems convenient for me - user will add new value and I will avoid handling duplicates. Second, I didn't know that Set is a complex object :-)  There will be no more than 20 items in Set, is it OK to use it?

Comment: A set is class instance, so it can't be (de)serialized without additional work. It more depends on what plans you have on your app. You may notice that it already doesn't work very well with Redux devtools - because only plain objects, arrays and primitives are expected. If you want to keep state unique, you can use Set to filter dupes out but store it as an array.

Comment: estus - really good point, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new set from the one in the state:

```js
const state =  new Set([5, 10, 15, 20]);
let newState = new Set(state);
// or: let newState = new Set([...state]);
console.log('state:', [...state]);
console.log('new state:', [...newState]);
state.add(11);
console.log('state:', [...state]);
console.log('new state:', [...newState]);
```

Comment: Thank you! Simple and elegant!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the set you want to duplicate to the constructor of the new set.
Like this:

```
let newSet = new Set(state)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks like I've duplicated issue  :-(